# Quickest way to preview a PIL image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, read-eval-print-loop

I'm now working with PIL images in Python. What's the quickest way to preview a PIL image in the Python shell? Saving to a file and then opening it in my OS is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: you could open it in a browser and press F5 every time you make a change. I don't think it's possible in python shell without a GUI for your program.

Comment: @Serdalis: As Michael Aaron Safyan showed below, it's indeed possible :)

Comment: definatly! that'll make my life easier too :D good question +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Image` class has a `show(self, title=None, command=None)` method, which you can use.

Comment: I've found that `show()` doesn't work in Windows 7, there's a bug.

Answer (score 3):

After installing [iPython](http://ipython.org/) and [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro), you can display PIL images inline in `ipython qtconsole` after executing the following code:

```
# display_pil.py
# source: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2012-March/009706.html
# by 'MinRK'
import Image
from IPython.core import display
from io import BytesIO

def display_pil_image(im):
    """displayhook function for PIL Images, rendered as PNG"""
    b = BytesIO()
    im.save(b, format='png')
    data = b.getvalue()

    ip_img = display.Image(data=data, format='png', embed=True)
    return ip_img._repr_png_()

# register display func with PNG formatter:
png_formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['image/png']
png_formatter.for_type(Image.Image, display_pil_image)
```

Example of usage:

```
import Image
import display_pil
im = Image.open('test.png')
im
```

`ipython qtconsole` will display the loaded image inline.

Comment: +1 This works for Ipython notebooks as well, a good way to document REPL experiments with images.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use `iPython` rather than the vanilla python interpreter.  Then you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` function with ease, and with the Qt console you can even get the images plotted inline in the interpreter.

[image]